# Unbind external service android Paho MQTT ServiceConnectionLeaked error

Tags: java, android, service, paho

What's the proper way to unbind an external service (located in another jar) file in Android?

I declare the service (located in `org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar`) in the manifest file as:

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
</service>
```

Service source [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/tree/org.eclipse.paho.android.service/org.eclipse.paho.android.service/src/org/eclipse/paho/android/service)

And the service runs properly. However, on exiting the app I get a `ServiceConnectionLeaked` error and after doing some searching I found that I need to call `unbindService(...);` on the `onDestroy()` method of the activity.

**Log:**

```
24915-24915/com.testapp.testmqtt E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.testapp.testmqtt.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$MyServiceConnection@426c50d8 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.testapp.testmqtt.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$MyServiceConnection@426c50d8 that was originally bound here
```

However, I do not have a `ServiceConnection` to pass to `unbindService()` since I'm not manually starting the service. Is there any way to obtain the `ServiceConnection` of that service and unbind it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just put this code in onDestroy of activity

```
    client.unregisterResources();
    client.close();
```